# Calculating areas.

Tags: code-golf

The smallest code that gives the area between the curve p(x) = a<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>1</sub>*x + a<sub>2</sub>*x<sup>2</sup> + ..., the line y = 0, the line x = 0 and the line x = C

(i.e. something like this:

[image: wanted area])

You can assume that p(x) >= 0 for x < C (bonus points if your code works for negative values of p(x)).

#### Input

C, a<sub>0</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>, ...

#### Output

a real number - the area

Example 1:

```
input: 2, 0, 1
output: 2.0
```

Examlpe 2:

```
input: 3.0, 0, 0.0, 2
output: 18
```

UPDATE:

- C > 0 is also assumed
- the area is between the curve, y=0, x=C **and x = 0**
- the input can be a list of any form; not necessarily comma separated.
- the output can be a real of any form (thus, '18' is a valid output, as is '18.0')

Comment: Since the answer is going to be "infinite" for almost any input, I think you've misstated the problem.

Comment: Should the input be read from standard input as a comma-separated string? Or can we write a function which takes a list of floats as an argument?

Comment: Do you mean between x=0, x=C, y=0, and the curve?

Comment: Can we assume that `C > 0`?

Comment: Also I assume that the output for the last case is supposed to be 18.0 or alternatively that it does not matter whether we add .0. Otherwise I do not understand why the first sample output ends in .0 and the second does not.

Comment: @Peter: I don't think so. He shows a picture of an inverse (the integral of which *would* diverge), but the function he specifies is a polynomial. The definite integral over [0,C) should be well defined and finite for finite coefficients.

Comment: @Peter: dmckee is right. I'll upload a more appropriate diagram later.

Comment: @sepp2k: list of floats is fine and yes C > 0 is assumed.

Comment: @Keith: yes, i forgot x=0.

Comment: @dmckee, I had noticed that, but my point was more that he was integrating a polynomial from -\infty to C, and for any non-trivial polynomial that diverges. The question has now been amended to fix this.

Comment: Can i accept the number of coefficients also in the input?

Comment: @AbelTom Well, formally not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Mathematica: 48 Chars

.

```
Sum[#[[i+1]]#[[1]]^i/i,{i,Length@#-1}]&@Input[]
```

Comment: -1 byte: `Length@#` -> `Tr[1^#]`. Also, you could omit `@Input[]` and make a function.

Answer (score 10):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
⊃⊥∘⌽⊢÷⍳∘≢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGCo@6WxSAPBfPMCDX8P@jruZHXUsfdcx41LP3Udeiw9sf9W4G8ToX/U8DKnjU2wdUcWi98aO2iUBdwUHOQDLEwzP4f5qCkYKBgiFXmoIxkDZQMAKyzBUMgaLGCiYKpgpmAA)

A tacit function that takes `C, a0, a1, ...` as a single vector argument.

**12 bytes** if a full program is needed. Note that, while the default representation for a numeric vector is the numbers separated by spaces (no comma or anything), it accepts comma-separated ones since `⎕` evals the input and `,` is the "concatenate" function.

```apl
(⊃⊥∘⌽⊢÷⍳∘≢)⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGCo@6WxSAPBfPMCDXkOtRR3vaf41HXc2PupY@6pjxqGfvo65Fh7c/6t0M4nUu0gSq/Q9U9J8zjctIwUDBkAvIMAYyDBSMQExzBUMFIwVjBRMFUwUzAA)

Uses `⎕IO←0` and `⎕DIV←1`, so that the range generation is 0-based and division by zero gives 0.

Because the polynomial is nonnegative and the integral starts at 0, it suffices to evaluate the antiderivative of the given polynomial at C.

The antiderivative of \$a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \dots\$ is \$a_0x + \frac{a_1}{2} x^2 + \frac{a_2}{3} x^3 + \dots\$. Because we have C attached to the start of the vector, we simply divide the entire array by their 0-based indexes:

```apl
       C  a0   a1   a2
input: 3  0    0    2
div  : 0  1    2    3
res  : 0  0    0    2/3
       0  a0/1 a1/2 a2/3
```

Then we simply evaluate the resulting polynomial at C.

#### How it works: the code

```apl
⊃⊥∘⌽⊢÷⍳∘≢  ⍝ Input: single array of C, a0, a1, a2, ...
      ⍳∘≢  ⍝ 0-based range 0, 1, 2, 3, ...
    ⊢÷     ⍝ Divide self by above
  ∘⌽       ⍝ Reverse
⊃⊥         ⍝ Convert from base C to real number
           ⍝ i.e. evaluate the polynomial, lowest term given last
```

Answer (score 5):

**Python - <strike>71</strike> 63 chars:**

```
a=input()
print sum(1.*a[i]*a[0]**i/i for i in range(1,len(a)))
```

It's a simple integration of a polynomial function between `0` and `C`.
And I haven't tested it, but I'm quite sure it works for negative values.

Comment: Learned something new about `input()` today:)

Answer (score 4):

### J, 26 characters

```
f=:3 :'((1}.y)&p.d._1)0{y'
```

e.g.

```
   f 2 0 1
2
   f 3 0 0 2
18
```

Comment: Neat!  I can't find a way to make it more tacit.  That `d.` being a conjunction doesn't make it very easy to my novice J skills.

Comment: @J-B: Yes, that d. is a "problem" for me too. :)

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 85 characters

```
f(c:l)=sum.map(\(i,x)->x*c**i/i)$zip[1..]l
main=getLine>>=print.f.read.('[':).(++"]")
```

Comment: The question isn't as strict as you treat it.  You could definitely simplify the input code, and possibly do away with explicit I/O altogether.

Answer (score 3):

## APL(NARS), 8 chars, 16 bytes

```
∘{⍵⊥⌽⍺}∫
```

The new NARS2000 function integrate, ∫.

it seems f∫b is integrate(f, 0..b)=∫_0^b f
Here i don't know if can be ok, the right argument is the max of interval of integration [0, max]
and the left argument is the list of numbers represent polinomy...

```
  f←∘{⍵⊥⌽⍺}∫
  0 1 f 2
2 
  0 0 2 f 3
18 
  1 2 3 4 5 6 f 7
137256
```

Comment: I don't know NARS, but if `∫` is a monadic operator and `∘` can bind two functions like Dyalog does, I guess `{⊥∘⌽∘⍵∫⍺}` could work at 9 chars.

Comment: @Bubbler so can be pheraps, less of 8 chars

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 65 chars

```
i=s=0
c=gets(q=",").to_f
$<.each(q){|a|s+=a.to_f*c**(i+=1)/i}
p s
```

The code reads until the end of input, not the end of the line. So you need to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to terminate input. (Pipe the input in using `echo` or from a file.)

Comment: i think assigning the "," to a variable will help...how about this `c=gets(q=",").to_f` and `$<.each(q){|a|s+=a.to_f*c**(i+=1)/i}`, saves one char....

Comment: Assigning `","` (or `?,`, which is even shorter) to `$/` allows you to omit the argument to `$<.each`. And `$<.map` is one character shorter than `$<.each`. ;)

Answer (score 2):

### C  GCC <s>186</s> 182 bytes

```
f(){i=0,l=1;float *d,s=0.0;d=malloc(sizeof(float)*50);scanf("%f",&d[0]);while(getchar()!='\n'){scanf("%f",&d[l]);l++;}for(i=0;i<l;i++)s+=d[i+1]*pow(d[0],(i+1))/(i+1);printf("%f",s);}
```

This program gives an output (area) for any curve between the curve, y=0, x=C and x=0. It can take coefficients (`float` as well) from a<sub>0</sub> to a<sub>48</sub>. The first accepted input is `C` followed by coefficients. Press `Ènter` after the last coefficient.

```
void f()
{
  int i=0,l=1;
  float *d,s=0.0;
  const int sz=100;
  d=malloc(sizeof(float)*sz);

  scanf("%f",&d[0]);
  while(getchar()!='\n')
  {
    scanf("%f",&d[l]);
    l++;
  }

  for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    s+=d[i+1]*pow(d[0],(i+1))/(i+1);

   printf("%f",s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 48 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z8tOjE@1so2uDQ3OjE6OlPbMDZWC8gAUnGZ@pk61Zk6hjo@qXnpJRkOibqGtbFADdUKRjoKBjoKQJ6@fkBRZl4JF1DQWM8ALGoAoo3gUv8B)

```
f[a_]:=Sum[a[[i+1]]*a[[1]]^i/i,{i,1,Length@a-1}]
```